# MYSQL - Select statement, if condition fail return empty string

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this query (MYSQL):

```
    SELECT agent.name,agency.title FROM agent, agency WHERE agent.id = "1"
    AND agent.titleid = agency.titleid
```

This will give me a record with the name and title, however if the second condition fail, the whole query will fall and it will display nothing.

Is it possible that if let's say the title cannot be found in `agency` table, then only display out the name and leave the title column blank.

What is the query to be able to do that?

Comment: Search for `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT agent.name,agency.title FROM agent
LEFT JOIN agency ON agent.titleid = agency.titleid
WHERE agent.id = "1"
```

Comment: You are much welcome @user1841098. GOD bless in your quest to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with a `LEFT JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.name, b.title 
FROM agent a
LEFT JOIN agency b 
ON a.titleid = b.titleid
WHERE a.id = '1'
```